# Select2: Remove item from selection when clicking anywhere on item, instead of cross

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Is there a clean way to remove the "cross" on the left-hand side of select2 items in a multi-select box, and have the functionality (removing the selected item on click) instead be enabled for the entire button? See pic; instead of clicking the red-highlighted cross to remove the item, I want to be able to click anywhere in the green-highlighted button.

Default functionality is to open the selection dropdown -- one could click anywhere in the text box instead. The cross, on the other hand, is tiny and easy to miss-click.

[image]

If there's no "clean" or "intended" way to go about this, suggestions for workaround are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it sorted. Downloaded the un-minified JS (4.0.6-rc.0) and did the following:

---

To remove the "cross," changed this

```
MultipleSelection.prototype.selectionContainer = function () {
        var $container = $(
        '<li class="select2-selection__choice">' +
            '<span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">' +
                '&times;' +
            '</span>' +
        '</li>'
    );
    return $container;
};
```

To this

```
MultipleSelection.prototype.selectionContainer = function () {
        var $container = $(
        '<li class="select2-selection__choice"></li>'
    );
    return $container;
};
```

---

To add the "unselect on tag click," added this on-click

```
this.$selection.on(
    'click',
    '.select2-selection__choice',
    function (evt) {
        // Ignore the event if it is disabled
        if (self.options.get('disabled')) {
            return;
        }

        var data = Utils.GetData(this, 'data');

        self.trigger('unselect', {originalEvent: evt, data: data})

        evt.stopPropagation()
    }
)
```

inside the function

```
MultipleSelection.prototype.bind = function (container, $container) {
    ...
}
```

(Very similar to the existing code that's in there to handle "cross" clicks normally)

And then finally, tweaked the relevant css from `cursor: default` to `cursor: pointer`

The final result:

[image: output]

Comment: M.chrichton just found your post which helped me to resolve my problem. Thanks for excellent post.

Comment: I appreciate the kudos, but I'd appreciate it more if you spelled my name correctly ;) Oh, and... voted on the question/answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this without modifying the source code would be to just make the footprint of the 'x' take up the size of the element:

```css
/* pillbox li container item */
.select2-selection__choice {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px; /* to account for the 'x' no longer taking up space */
}

/* the 'x' */
.select2-selection__choice__remove {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; /* to fill width */
    padding-left: 5px; /* whatever matches your pillbox padding */

    color: transparent !important; /* hide the x */
}
```